# Python: SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

Having read this [answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/42773096/4487805), I tried to do the following to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

So I did below. Yet it still generates the warning below. What have I done wrong ?

```
df_filtered.loc[:,'MY_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['MY_DT'])
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

My column was originally a string

```
df_filtered['MY_DT']
Out[3]: 
0       4/24/2020
1       4/24/2020
2       4/24/2020
3       4/24/2020
10      4/24/2020
          ...    
1937    4/30/2020
1938    4/30/2020
1939    4/30/2020
1940    4/30/2020
1941    4/30/2020
Name: MY_DT, Length: 1896, dtype: object
```

Comment: Presumably `df_filtered` is a slice of another `DataFrame`? You don't show enough of your code for us to be certain.

Comment: Yes it is a slice of another dataframe.

Comment: Then that's the problem - you need to make a copy of the slice before you perform any assignments - see theletz's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `df_filtered` is a sub dataframe of other one (`df`?).

This warning means that you try to change `df_filtered` which is a slice of `df`, and it will not change `df`.

In order to avoid this warning you can try to copy the slice:

```
df_filtered = df_filtered.copy()
```